# How to sum up values of span with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple calculator:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes


    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());

    $('#added').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/1

What I need, is to sum up the values that get calculated in the spans : budgetI + actualI

How can I take those two values, and put them in a sum?

Comment: you need to have your code in the question... not just the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

If the input is empty, parseFloat() can return `NaN` that could be the problem. You can assign the value `0` if `parseFloat` returns `NaN` using

```
$('input').keyup(function () { // run anytime the value changes
    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val()) || 0;

    $('#added').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mhhda2uh/)

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes   

    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val()) || 0;

    $('#added').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="first"></input><br />

<input id="second"></input><br />

<input id="third"></input><br />
Total:<span id="added"></span><br />
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/c6pfbhew/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
  var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());

  if(!isNaN(firstValue) && !isNaN(secondValue) && !isNaN(thirdValue))
  {
     $('#added').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pzkeujjp/)

Comment: @Dan..check fiddle plz

Comment: Ok but it only works if all three inputs have values, worth noting.

Comment: @Dan..OP wants to sum all three inputs ... so sum should be calculated if all three inputs are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that this is what you want.

Here's the html.

```
<input id=first></input><br />

<input id=second></input><br />

<input id=third></input><br />
Total:<span id=added></span><br />
```

Here's the javascript

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes


    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val()) || 0;

    $('#added').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
});
```